# Using FindInMap for Location Parameter in Fn::Transform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When I try and use the `Fn::FindInMap` function to provide the location for the snippet in a `Fn::Transform` section I am getting this error

> Failed to digest functions within transform parameters, intrinsic functions in transform block must only contain parameter values or stack metadata.

In the documentation it says I am allowed to do that.
[Here is the documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-transform.html)

Here are the two relevant sections of my template

```
Fn::Transform:
  Name: 'AWS::Include'
  Parameters: {Location: {'Fn::FindInMap': [PipelineStackMap, dev, Location]}}


Mappings:
  PipelineStackMap:
    prod:
      Location: "s3://my-prod-cicd-bucket/pipeline.yml"
    dev:
      Location: "s3://my-cicd-bucket/pipeline.yml"
    qa:
      Location: "s3://my-cicd-bucket/pipeline.yml"
```

It works fine when I use `Ref` and a variable or when I hard code the bucket string, just not when using `FindInMap`.

Answer (score 2):

Curious if you ever resolved this? My guess is this is a problem with AWS documentation. It provides this example, then proceeds to say that no Fn:s are supported.

Comment: I see the same thing.  Did you resolve this?